# Sending email after Login Django Allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I’m new using Django Allauth, is there a way I can implement sending email after login? For example; every time someone logged into my account I will receive an email automatically.

Comment: You can override the login form and add whatever you want there.  Checkout https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#login-allauth-account-forms-loginform.  For example you can add code to send you email using [django's email functionality](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/email/)

Comment: Thanks…. Just a question, will your answer above be but in the forms.py or the views.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**
You can override the login form and add whatever you want there. Checkout [this](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#login-allauth-account-forms-loginform). For example you can add code to send you email using django's [email](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/email/) functionality.

The custom login form will probably be in the `accounts` app.  Within this directory you can add a **forms.py** with the following, which will overrride (well, not really override, rather, add to) **allauth**'s login form.

```py
# forms.py

from django import forms
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm

class MyCustomLoginForm(LoginForm):

    def login(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # HERE is where you would add additional processing whenever someone logs in
        # using allauth, ending with the actual sending of the message you want:
        # ...
        send_mail(
            "Subject here",
            "Here is the message.",
            "from@example.com",
            ["to@example.com"],
            fail_silently=False,
        )

        # You must return the original result.
        return super(MyCustomLoginForm, self).login(*args, **kwargs)
```

Make sure to add the following to **settings.py** so that django knows to use this custom login form instead of the one from **allauth** (even though you will actually be using allauth's login form, just with extra stuff added):

```py
# settings.py

ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'login': 'accounts.forms.MyCustomLoginForm'}
```

Also understand that you will probably be making other changes in **settings.py** depending on which email server you are using (for example, with [Zoho](https://www.zoho.com/mail/) you'd need to do follow [Zoho Django Configuration](https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/community/topic/how-to-configure-django-settings) in your settings to get it to work.

You shouldn't need to mess with **views.py** as all the processing is done in the overridden form.

**NOTE:** Although this *should* work, I have not had time to test it!

Comment: Yes, how can I send mail to recipient email address that’s already store in my USER ADMIN? For example I have multiple users in admin with different email address… I want it A user login that user receives an email to his registered email address in Admin… so on with others.

Comment: Just use `self.user.email` in the to: field list.  I thought you wanted an email sent to *you*.

Comment: Okay works nice… Thanks. I honestly want to learn more, you can suggest me a good platform to learn. Thanks

Comment: If you mean more about Django, then the best is to start with them: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial01/ and https://learndjango.com/ for more, including allauth.